# How to get response like this by using a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, join

I want to get a response from web API from database using a stored procedure.

**Table 1**

```
CustomerID | Offer
CustomerID ==> PK as well as FK for selfrefrencing
```

**Table 2**

```
ProductID| CustomerID ===>Child Table
```

I want response like this in json by using a stored procedure:

```
{
  CustomerID:abc
  Offer:1000
  Bid:500 Logical column
  [
    {
      ProductID:123
      CustomerID:22
    }
  ]
```

Comment: How do you join these tables to get the expected output? If you join on `CustomerID`, why `CustomerID` has two different values in the output JSON. And, most important, post sample data in the question.

Comment: can you throw few input data of both table.

Comment: what have you tried so far and please provide sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that might get you started. You can run this in SSMS.

```
DECLARE @Main TABLE ( MainId VARCHAR(3), Offer INT, Bid INT );
INSERT INTO @Main ( MainId, Offer, Bid ) VALUES ( 'abc', 1000, 500 );

DECLARE @Sub TABLE ( fkMainId VARCHAR(3), ProductID INT, CustomerID INT );
INSERT INTO @Sub ( fkMainId, ProductID, CustomerID ) VALUES ( 'abc', 123, 22 );

SELECT
    MainId, Offer, Bid, Sub.Items
FROM @Main AS Main
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT (
        SELECT ProductID, CustomerID FROM @Sub WHERE fkMainId = Main.MainId FOR JSON PATH
    ) AS Items

) AS Sub
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

Returns:

```
{"MainId":"abc","Offer":1000,"Bid":500,"Items":[{"ProductID":123,"CustomerID":22}]}
```

Beautified:

```
{
    "MainId": "abc",
    "Offer": 1000,
    "Bid": 500,
    "Items": [{
        "ProductID": 123,
        "CustomerID": 22
    }]
}
```

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 not supporting JSON PATH

Comment: what is fkMainId here

Comment: My apologies as your version of SQL Server was not clear. Have you considered using XML as opposed to JSON then? SQL 2008 offers native support for XML, and you can easily modify this example to use FOR XML, rather than FOR JSON. As for the column, fkMainId, it is a foreign key that relates to @Main in my example data. You would need to reference your table relationships.